# what is wrong with the spaces in this string?

Tags: bash-scripting, trim

i have following string (a version number): `2.2.0 (15)`.
but the problem is, I can't trim the whitespaces. are there some curious whitespaces in bash?
because if I do this:

```
  local test="  ${var}  "
  local version="$(echo ${test} | xargs)" # also tried ` tr -s ' ' and sed...`
  echo "_${var}|${test}|${version}_"
```

the result is `_ 2.2.0 (15) |   2.2.0 (15)   | 2.2.0 (15) _`
so it trims the spaces I added manually, but not the spaces in my initial string. how is this possible?

Comment: What is `var`? Is it `2.2.0 (15)`? If so, then the resulting string is *different* for me (`_2.2.0 (15)|  2.2.0 (15)  |2.2.0 (15)_`). Please [edit] and create a codeblock that starts with `var=`, so when you paste it in a *fresh* shell (and I understand the shell is Bash) it replicates the problem *for you*. And by "paste" I mean "paste from this site", not from your source. Then it will probably replicate the problem for us. `version="$(echo ${test} | xargs)"` is weird code and I don't know if it's a part of the problem or something you really want to do. What is your desired output exactly?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem. Probably you did something wrong in your function. I am getting `_ 2.2.0 (15) |   2.2.0 (15)   |2.2.0 (15)_` here with `var=' 2.2.0 (15) '` (the triple spaces are displayed as single spaces here for the middle term).

Comment: as you can see in the output `var` is  `2.2.0 (15)` but with a space in the front and a space in the back. and my question is: why could bash not trim this spaces? one minute ago here was a comment with hexdump. I did this and I think the problem is, that these spaces aren't spaces... hexdump result is `1b 5b 3f 32 35 6c 20 32  2e 32 2e 30 20 28 31 35 29 20 1b 5b 3f 32 35 68  0a` - converted in an online converter it is `[?25l 2.2.0 (15) [?25h`

Comment: ah maybe this is because the cli output with this version number is colored?

Comment: `1b 5b 3f 32 35 6c` can be represented as `\e[?25l` where `\e` is the escape character. The sequence hides the cursor (search for `DECTCEM` [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)). Your problem is not with spaces, your problem is because of [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).

Comment: but is there no way to get rid of this "G" ?

Comment: @m1well Well, in general like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14684/108618) or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/628899/108618). The best method is to work with data not destined for a terminal from the very beginning; i.e. not to populate your `var` from data destined for a terminal, use a better source. Side note: your `echo ${test} | xargs` is poor code because `var='-n foo'` [will surprise you](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618) and `var='/*'` [will surprise you even more](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/108618).